# Get IQueryable from TFS work items

Tags: linq, tfs, tfs-workitem

I need to get **IQueryable** of TFS work items, which supports **OrderBy**, **Take** and **Skip** methods (required for paging and sorting). I used **Wilinq** linq provider but it does not prepare these methods.

Is there any other way to get IQueryable from work items?
Do TFS API or any other library provide solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `IQueryable` to use LINQ, you need an `IEnumerable`, which includes arrays.

A [work item query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140399(v=vs.120).aspx) returns a `WorkItemCollection`, which through a chain of interface inheritance, implements `IEnumerable`. You may have to use a `Cast<WorkItem>()` to turn it into an `IEnumerable<WorkItem>`, but it should work.

Comment: IQueryable is needed because I want to use it with our framework, IEnumerable and Linq are not enough for this case.

Comment: @Mahdi Then call `AsQueryable` on the collection.

Comment: This IQueryable does not work, because all data is retrieved when we call Cast method. I need real IQuieryable like that is generated by libraries like **Wilinq**, which until we do not access one of members or do not use methods like ToList or Cast, data does not get fetched.